# private fields in parent class - java

Tags: java, inheritance, private

```
class Parent{
    private int a = 10;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
} 

class Child extends Parent{ 
    public int b = 20;
    public void getSuperA() {
        System.out.print(getA()); // getA() instead of a
    }
}
```

when we creating a child class object only one object will create. what are the members in that object ? what will happen to the private field in the Parent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate an object of child class.

- All fields of parent as well as child class are initialized, irrespective of access modifier (private, protected or public)
- Constructor of parent class is called.
- Constructor of child class is called.

---

So the fields will exist (and they will store a value), but you won't be able to access them if they are private.

The public method returning a private field will grant you that access. In a nutshell, it will work.

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit** (in response to the comment):

The mechanism is built right into the language for security. Access modifiers provide information required to that mechanism.

- A private field can only be accessed from **within** the class.
- It will be **present** but not **visible** from outside.
- You can sense it's presence by the effect it has on the behavior of some of the public methods of that class (ones which use it). Since those methods are members of the same class, they can access the private field.

*Benefits:*

- You can hide implementation details from outside.
- You can restrict the improper usage of the fields through method.

Example

```
private int salary;

public void setSalary(int newSalary) {
    if (newSalary < MAX_SALARY) {
        this.salary = newSalary;
    } else {
        this.salary = MAX_SALARY;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes true. but, if the private field live with in the Child object why can not directly access it with in child object ? what is the mechanism behind to restrict that ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The child object will hold a value for the parent's private field, but because it's private in `Parent` the only way for anyone (including the child object itself) to *access* the value is via the methods inherited from the parent class.

Comment: but, if the private field live with in the Child object why can not directly access it with in child object ? what is the mechanism behind to restrict that ? thank you

Comment: You can access it in child object. You just cannot access directly from Parent.

Answer (score 0):

Chile object's fields are created.
First fields are initialised, then constructor is invoked.
In your case field a will be initialised with value 10.

Comment: is that private field live with in child class object ?

Comment: Yes, it's live. Parent cannot see it directly by it might invoke getA()

Answer (score 0):

it seems you know if you do something

```
 Child ch = new Child()
```

and then

```
ch.a;
```

obviously not working, because it's private
but when an object extends from a parent class it inherits all the public and private attribute so you have to define a function in Parent class like

```
public int getA(){
   return a;
}
```

and later on in ch you can access a like this :

```
ch.getA();
```

Comment: yes true. but, if the private field live with in the Child object why can not directly access it with in child object ? what is the mechanism behind to restrict that ? thank you

Comment: I don't consider it as a restriction , the private field is supposed to be like this only accessible within the Class that defined it, firstly we should be aware of Object Oriented in Java and then develop our code, so if we define something as private we should have known how it behaves